# Horizontally align div with an element outside its parent

Tags: css

This image shows what I am trying to do. [image]

Basically, I have a `header` and `footer` inside the body. I have a `div1` inside a `header` which has a size that can vary. I want to align `div2`, which is inside the `footer`, so that its right border is matches the right border of `div1`.

The following HTML can explain the structure.

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be the css.

```
#div1 {
        overflow: auto;
        display: grid;
        float: start;
}

#div2 {
    width: 20px;
    // ??????
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have more CSS code? the actual shows nothing

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is a hypothetical situation I made up to represent in a simpler way my actual program. I made a structure that is equivalent to my actual code and made a diagram with word because I cannot get div2 and div1 to horizontally align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `float: start`. You just be better off having a common container, as how it is in Bootstrap and other frameworks to "contain" your code. So your page might be rendered well this way:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  background: #ffa500;
}

#header {
  background-color: #fcc;
  padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #f99;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 65%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#div1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #99f;
}

#div2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccf;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="div1">
      div1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="div2">
      div2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Hey man thanks for your answer. I am not too sure I understand how this works. You said that both items are in a common container? The footer and header seem to be completely different containers.

Comment: @ThomasFromUganda I just added the code too. LoL. See the common `container`? Or better off, `<div class="container">` surrounds both the header and footer, if that's what your question is?

Comment: I am not sure to understand. According to the snippet you posted, there are two divs with the container class, one in the footer and one in the header, so those would be two different divs? I don't understand why it is common if there are two different container divs.

Comment: It's just common class name only. And that gives you a common design... Something like this, if that makes any sense at all. That's how most of the front end frameworks work. There will be too many repetitions... So yes. `:)`

Comment: @ThomasFromUganda And ps: My solution is responsive... `;)`

Comment: Ohh, I thought you were trying to say that there was only one div the the container class. Thanks for your help!